# Check if a type implements a generic interface without considering the generic type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface

I have an interface

```
public interface MyInterface<TKey, TValue>
{
}
```

Implementations are irrelevant. Now I want to check if a given type is an implementation of that interface. This method fails for

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface<int, string>
{
}
```

But I don't know how to do the check.

```
public void CheckIfTypeImplementsInterface(Type type)
{
    var result1 = typeof(MyInterface<,>).IsAssignableFrom(type); --> false
    var result2 = typeof(MyInterface<int,string>).IsAssignableFrom(type); --> true
}
```

What do I have to do for result1 to be true?

Comment: Have you considered making a `MyInterface` interface and have `MyInterface<TKey, TValue> : MyInterface`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to get all interfaces and see if the generic definition matches the required interface type.

```
bool result1 = type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
    .Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .Contains(typeof(MyInterface<,>));
```

EDIT: As Jon points out in the comments, you could also do:

```
bool result1 = type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
    .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyInterface<,>));
```

Comment: You could change your last two to: `.Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyInterface<,>))`

Comment: You can further simplify to one lambda, with `.Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyInterface<,>))` (removing the need for `.Where`, since `.Any` is already filtering the items)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, such behavior is only required in cases where an interface contains some functionality which does not depend upon the generic type parameters.  If you have control over the interfaces, the best solution is to have the type-dependent parts inherit from a non-type dependent part.  For example, if the existing collection interfaces didn't exist, one might define them something like:

```
interface ICountable 
  { CollectionAttribute Attributes {get;} int Count {get;} }
interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> ICountable
  { ... and other stuff ... }
```

Had such a thing been done with `ICollection`, then code which was expecting an `IEnumerable<Animal>` but got an object of type `CatList` that just implements `IList<Cat>` would have no problem using the `Count` member of that object (note that `List<Animal>` implements the non-generic `ICollection`, but other `IList<Animal>` implementations may not).

As it is, if you're stuck with the task of having code somehow find the `Count` method of `ICollection<Cat>` when you're expecting an `IEnumerable<Animal>`, it may be worthwhile to build something like a `Dictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<Animal>, int>` so that once you've found that `CatList` implements `ICollection<Cat>.Count` you can construct a delegate to a method which will cast its argument to `ICollection<Cat>`, call `Count` on it, and return its result.  If you have such a dictionary, then if you're given another `CatList` you'll be able to simply invoke the delegate from the dictionary.

Comment: Totally aggree, but in my case I just want to do a basic check in a Attribute `[CustomAttribute(typeof(ClassName))]` and I require ClassName to implement the interface.Later in code, I know both generic attributes and can use reflection to create a new instance of ClassName