# Infer Generic Type of Interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

-- Context

I have the following 5 objects

```
IChangeStatus<T>
myFirstClass : IChangeStatus<firstClassEnum>
mySecondClass : IChangeStatus<secondClassEnum>

myClassHandler<TEntity>
myFirstClassHandler : myClassHandler<myFirstClass>
```

for the purposes of the question we can assume the interface only has the property

```
T Status { get; }
```

-- Questions

1.- How can I ask in a method in `myClassHandler` if an instance of TEntity implements `IChangeStatus`?

2.- How can I iterate over an IEnumerable of `TEntity` assuming their specific IChangeStatus?

Comment: Regarding question #1 - are you looking for a way to check, at runtime, it TEntity implements IChangeStatus, or a way to ensure, at compile-time, that TEntity will always be of type IChangeStatus?

Comment: I just saw this comment, I was looking for a runtime check, I already found it in another SO question, is in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this other [SO Question - Check if a type implements a generic interface without considering the generic type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233390/check-if-a-type-implements-a-generic-interface-without-considering-the-generic-t) which gave me a more generic answer which is what I was looking for:

```
return entity.GetType().GetInterfaces()
       .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
       .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IChangeStatus<>));
```

As to the iteration over the IEnumerable assuming the specific type of IChangeStatus, since we got that to point then the type does implement the interface thus has a Status property... so I went for [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type.

Answer (score 2):

To check if your class implements IChangeStatus, you can simply do:

```
public void FooMethod(ClassType myClass)
{
  var doesImplementIChange = myClass as IChangeStatus<SomeClass>
  if (doesImplementIChange != null)
  {
    // Do stuff..
  }
}
```

To iterate over an IEnumerable of your classes:

```
foreach (var data in myClass.OfType<MyType>())
        {
            // Do stuff..
        }
```

or, you could do:

```
foreach (var cls in myClass)
        {
            var myCls = myClass as IChangeStatus<SomeClass>;
            if (myCls != null)
            {
                // Do stuff..
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the way I have it implemented, but that list of ifs is what I don't like... I thought maybe there was a better solution.

Comment: As to checking id if it implements the interface, there is no alternative to a cast and null check. But for the foreach statement you can use the first option where you wont have any if statements

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `T` from `IChangeStatus<T>` in `MyClassHandler`, you will have to add another type parameter. For example:

```
class MyClassHandler<TEntity, TStatus>
    where TEntity : IChangeStatus<TStatus>
{
     public IEnumerable<TStatus> Statuses
     {
          get { return _entities.Select(entity => entity.Status); }
     }
}
```

The `where` clause will ensure that the entity and status types are correlated.

If you don't want to do that, you could add an additional non-generic interface that exposes a `Status` property of the type `Object`. You'd lose some static typing that way, but you would not need the extra type parameter.