# Treat variable as List if template is List<>

Tags: c#

I must create the List filled with data if template is a List. I have a function

```
    static T GenerateRandomFields<T>() where T:new()
    {
        var ret= new T();

        if (typeof(T)==typeof(List<>))
        {
            var leng = rnd.Next(50);
            List<typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0]> test;
            for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
                ((List<>)ret).Add(...);
            return ret;
        }
        ...
    }
```

But it's impossible to cast ret as List. How to add data to ret?

Comment: Your method signature specifies that the return type is `T`, not `List<T>`. What are you trying to do? If T is a List, do you want to return a `List<List<TWhatever>>`?

Comment: You could create another method with an `IList<TItem>` constraint. That would allow you to use `IList<T>` methods directly, like `ret.Add` and return that list

Comment: Is it meaningful and correct to call this method for a non-collection type `T`? The method name sounds a lot like it is only meant for collections anyway.

Comment: Don't do this.  This is an abuse of generics. Generics are supposed to be **generic**; if you have behaviour that is **specialized** to lists then it is not **generic**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'll have to use reflection. When you know the type parameters during compile time, you would make a simple generic method:

```
public static IList<T> GenerateRandomList<T>() where T : new() {
    var list = new List<T>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    var leng = rnd.Next(50);

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.Max(leng, 1); i++) {
        var newItem = new T();
        list.Add(newItem);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Now, you have to connect this method with your existing method. At first you'll need `MethodInfo` pointing to the generic method (my class is named `Q42117838`):

```
static MethodInfo genericMethod = typeof(Q42117838).GetMethod(nameof(GenerateRandomList));
```

Secondly, we'll declare a cache for the methods we'll call with the actual list types:

```
static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> methods = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
```

And we can put it together:

```
public static T GenerateRandomFields<T>() where T : new() {
    if (typeof(System.Collections.IList).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
        var listType = typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0];
        MethodInfo method;

        if (!methods.TryGetValue(listType, out method))
            methods.Add(listType, method = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(listType));

        return (T)method.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Please note that the test

```
if (typeof(T)==typeof(List<>))
```

doesn't work and that there seems to be no easy way to check for a generic `IList<>` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233390/check-if-a-type-implements-a-generic-interface-without-considering-the-generic-t)) so I'm using the non-generic variant which will work.

Now you have the choice, call:

- `var x = Q42117838.GenerateRandomList<int>()`  (*preferred*, because you know the type at compile time)
- `var x = Q42117838.GenerateRandomFields<List<int>>()`